# phpMyAdmin wants HTTPS- where can I get it?

Tags: phpmyadmin

today I installed PHPMyAdmin with Xampp.
I configured the module Apache with my data.
After filling in my data I get the Info "Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin."

What is wrong here and what can I do to change it?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Kind regards from Germanx
Alex

P.S. I am not an expert ... ;-)

After looking in the web and reading on several pages I don't know yet what to do.